# Create custom notification android

Tags: android, android-notifications

How to create custom default notification? I am using Remote view to create the notification. but its not what was expect. Below is the image attched. I want to create the notification as that, with two button at bottom(like The Big Meeting is defined.
Any tutorial will be really helpful.

[image]

Below is code snippet what I have written.

```
Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(LockableActivity.INTENT_SNOOZE);
        PendingIntent pendingSnoozeIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, snoozeIntent, 0);

        Intent gotItIntent = new Intent(LockableActivity.INTENT_GOT_IT);
        PendingIntent pendingGotItIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, gotItIntent, 0);

        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.view_notification);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_title, entity.getClientName() + " appointment is late");
        remoteView.setTextColor(R.id.tv_title, context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
        remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_snooze, pendingSnoozeIntent);
        remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_got_it, pendingGotItIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle(entity.getClientName() + " appointment is late")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(context.getString(R.string.notification_content)))
                        .setContent(remoteView);
```

But here I have my xml. Is there other way by which I could DD THE BUTTONs at bottom.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your remote view to the bigContentView field in the notification

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(entity.getClientName() + " appointment is late")
        .setAutoCancel(true).build();
notification.bigContentView = remoteView;
mNotificationManager .notify(0,notification);
```

Comment: As I am using Notification.Builder I dont ~notification.bigContentView = remoteView;~ get to see this way of assigned the big content view

Comment: recheck the code in my answer  to see that .build() on line 4 returns a notification from builder

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, But I got the answer. notification.addAction() was the answer to my question. Thanks anyways